# How to do a wildcard search in C# on ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am using MVC3, C#, .net4.0

I have objects that contain a search string with which I can use to search for the relevant objects ie for 4 objects:

```
[car:vw:engine:1800]
[car:vw:engine:Diesel 1800]
[car:vw:engine:1600]
[car:ford:engine:1800]
```

I would like to search for objects that have a make of "vw" and "1800" engine.

I could try Contains():

```
SearchString.Contains("vw:engine:1800")
```

Which will return just one object.

I need something like:

```
SearchString.Contains("vw:engine:*1800")
```

Where * is a wildcard and would pick up :

```
[car:vw:engine:1800]
[car:vw:engine:Diesel 1800]
```

The only way around this, at present, would be:

```
SearchString.Contains("vw:engine:1800") or 
SearchString.Contains("vw:engine:Diesel 1800")
```

Is there a simple way to do this using a mainstream .net function like Contains(), if not Contains() itself.

There is a good reason for me using a search string like this, but this is not part of the question.

Comment: Did you try `Regex.IsMatch()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to check if `SearchString` is a match. `.*` means zero or more of any characters and is used in place of your wildcard.

```
string pattern = @"^\[car:vw:engine:.*1800]$";
bool matches = Regex.IsMatch(SearchString, pattern);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes regex could be very powerful for my needs. I am implementing a rule processor whereby the rules are stored in a DB, and therefore "Regex.IsMatch(SearchString, pattern)" is the rule. Need to play with this, could be powerful though. Out of interest is this the only simple way of trying to achieve this? I can only really use mainstream functions in my stored expressions for the rule to work. I use FLEE. It is great.

Comment: @SamJolly I'm pretty sure it's not the only way, but using regex is a simple and powerful way **if used correctly**. Just don't try to solve every problem with regex.

Comment: @Szymon - What type of scenarios would you say would be a bad choice to use regular expressions for these types of problems?

Comment: @user3241191 First of all don't try regex on HTML or XML, use a parser. I personally don't use regex in situations that are too complex as it usually creates more problems.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I'd prefer the regular expressions.
In your particular case you could use something like this:

```
        string car1 = "[car:vw:engine:Diesel 1800]";
        string car2 = "[car:vw:engine:1800]";

        var tokens1 = car1.Substring(1, car1.Length - 2).Split(':');
        var tokens2 = car2.Substring(1, car2.Length - 2).Split(':');

        bool IsMatch1 = tokens1[3].EndsWith("1800");
        bool IsMatch2 = tokens2[3].EndsWith("1800");
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. Slightly long winded. I think regex is more suitable.